# Can't access global Swap function within from a class

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment, swap

this is my first question on the site.

A little problem met me today. I can't call a global function `Swap` within a assignment operator and move constructor from the DynamicArray template class. When I try to do this I get an error C2660 saying:

```
'DynamicArray<int>::Swap' : function does not take 2 arguments.
```

It's strange for me, because I can call this function with 2 arguments in main function. Does anyone know what is the reason of that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

template <typename T>
class DynamicArray;

template <typename T>
inline void Swap(DynamicArray<T>& lhs, DynamicArray<T>& rhs) {

    lhs.Swap(rhs);
}

template <typename T>
class DynamicArray {

public:
    DynamicArray(size_t Size = 0, T Content = T())
        : m_Size(Size), m_Array(Size ? new T[m_Size] : nullptr) {

        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Size; ++i) {

                m_Array[i] = Content;
        }
    }

    DynamicArray(const DynamicArray<T>& rhs)
        : m_Size(rhs.m_Size), m_Array(m_Size ? new T[m_Size] : nullptr) {

        std::copy(rhs.m_Array, rhs.m_Array + m_Size, m_Array);
    }

    DynamicArray(DynamicArray<T>&& rhs)
        : DynamicArray<T>() {

        this->Swap(rhs);
        //Swap(*this, rhs);         //C2660
    }

    DynamicArray<T>& operator= (DynamicArray<T> rhs) {

        this->Swap(rhs);
        //Swap(*this, rhs);         //C2660

        return *this;
    }

    ~DynamicArray() {

        delete [] m_Array;
    }

    void Swap(DynamicArray<T>& rhs) {

        std::swap(m_Size, rhs.m_Size);
        std::swap(m_Array, rhs.m_Array);
    }

private:
    size_t m_Size;
    T* m_Array;
};

int main() {

    DynamicArray<int> DA1(4, 64);
    DynamicArray<int> DA2(2, 33);

    DA1 = std::move(DA2);     //using move constructor

    DynamicArray<int> DA3(8, 4);
    DynamicArray<int> DA4(2, 55);

    DA3 = DA4;                //using assignment operator

    Swap(DA1, DA3);           //here I can call this function with 2 arguments

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Try `Swap<int>(DA1, DA3);` Looks like `T` can't be automatically deduced from `DynamicArray<int>`.

Comment: There's only one candidate found via name lookup, and that's the one in your class. The outer scope isn't searched if there is one found already. Thus, you have to qualify it or bring it into scope.

Comment: Looks like `DynamicArray` defines its own `Swap` function which shadows the global one. Try `::Swap(*this,rhs)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify that you want to call the global Swap, you should prefix it perhaps with the scope resolution operator `::`, like this `::Swap(...)`.

It's been a long while since I last coded in c++ but I believe the member Swap method takes precedence in the resolution of the Swap symbol, when it's used within a member method.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly use std::swap function try:

```
void Swap(DynamicArray<T>& rhs)
{
   using std::swap;
   std::swap(m_Size, rhs.m_Size);
   std::swap(m_Array, rhs.m_Array);
}

DynamicArray(DynamicArray<T>&& rhs)
            : DynamicArray<T>()
{
   this->Swap(rhs);
} 
...
Swap<int>( DA1, DA3 );
```

but I would remove global `inline void Swap(DynamicArray<T>` and start using:

```
DA1.Swap( DA3 );
```